# How to add custom attribute to all simple_form input based on model name and attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I want to add a custom attribute to every input generated by simple_form. The attribute value is based on model name and field. So I did this:

```
# app/inputs/base.rb
class Base < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input_html_options
    super['custom-attr'] = "#{object_name}.#{attribute_name}"
  end
end
```

This isn't working. The code is not being loaded for execution at all. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add code in `lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb`, code should look like this to make sure it can be loaded automatically

```
module SimpleForm
  module Inputs
    class Base
      def input_html_options
        @input_html_options...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or use `class_eval` in `config/initializers/simple_form_ext.rb` like this

```
SimpleForm::Inputs::Base.class_eval do
  def input_html_options
    @input_html_options[:'custom-attr'] = "#{object_name}.#{attribute_name}"
    @input_html_options
  end
end
```